# Mongo Schema Design

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema, php-mongodb, database

I'm pretty new to Mongo. Just started a project using Mongodb as the database.
I'm not sure how should i design the following use-case to a document base database.

User-Case 
1. Vendor/Distributor has a list of product on our system.
2. There's a standard price list of each product for any customers.
3. Vendor/Distributor also has customize price list of each of the product for each customer.
eg. CustA have a productA at different pricing from the standard and it's only available to him.
4. Some of the Product are only available through customize price, and I match those product with attribute public = false.

How should i work this out in document base database?
Current design i have is.
1. [**Product Document**] with embedded document of standard price list. 
2. [**Product_Price Document**] with oneToMany link [**Product Document**] and oneToMany to [**Customer Document**]
3. [**Customer Document**].

With this Model, I'm facing problem with querying by paging.
Example I query the first 30 Product sorted by name. Then query [**Product_Price Document**] with the 30 ProductId that match, so that I have those customize price for that customer who login.

The problems come where by I couldn't query item that are customize to the user that is not available for everyone.

Is there a better way or design the schema or what should i do with the query?

I'm using PHP, Doctrine2, Symfony2

Comment: In this case you should embed a price list for every customer, using the product pricelist as it's initial version. From that point on only query the customer price lists. Data duplication is a bit of a pain but hard to avoid in non-relational schemas. Duplication allows for single document fetches which is what provided the high performance. Type out your intended schema in MongoDB format (JSON) and add it to your question and I'll have a look at editing it to allow the queries you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you query the **Product_Price_Document** query it using both ProductID and current CustomerID. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bashar Abdullah!!
Yes I'm querying the Product_Price_Document using both ProductId and CustomerId.

Comment: It seems to me you should be getting the results you want here. But take a look at other comments and answers suggesting embedded document may not be bad option at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would structure it.

Have two collections:
 - Products
 - Vendors

Your products table would have the list of all your products and their standard price. Your vendors page would have an array of product ID's along with an override price in the case that they have a different price for that particular product.

If you are also tracking customers then you could make that a collection too and have a belongs to relationship almost to the vendors.

so in short:

```
collection.vendor:
 {"name":'foo',"products":[{"_id":mongoId,"priceOveride":15.50},..]}

collection.products:
 {"name":"bar","price":15.40}
```

Excellent resource for reading a bit more into the relationships which you can use:
[Learn Mongo Interactively](http://www.mongly.com/)

Comment: Thanks Frederico for the feedback. and the Link!! Learn alot more with Mongo. Just one more quick question.
If product_priceOverride has multi of them because each customer might have different price. How can I still link a customer to a embedded priceOverride? or is that even possible?

Comment: ah if each customer has a price override; then I'd place that on the users collection.